# How to eliminate email formatting in received email?

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am practicing sending emails with Google App Engine with Python. This code checks to see if `message.sender` is in the database:

```
class ReceiveEmail(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        querySender = User.all()
        querySender.filter("userEmail =", message.sender)
        senderInDatabase = None
        for match in querySender:
            senderInDatabase = match.userEmail
```

This works in the development server because I send the email as `"az@example.com"` and `message.sender="az@example.com"`

But I realized that in the production server emails come formatted as `"az <az@example.com>` and my code fails because now `message.sender="az <az@example.com>"` but the email in the database is simple `"az@example.com".`

I searched for how to do this with `regex` and it is possible but I was wondering if I can do this with Python lists? Or, what do you think is the best way to achieve this result? I need to take just the email address from the `message.sender`.

[App Engine documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html) acknowledges the formatting but I could not find a specific way to select the email address only.

Thanks!

**EDIT2** (re: Forest answer)

@Forest:
`parseaddr()` appears to be simple enough:

```
>>> e = "az <az@example.com>"
>>> parsed = parseaddr(e)
>>> parsed
('az', 'az@example.com')
>>> parsed[1]
'az@example.com'
>>>
```

But this still does not cover the other type of formatting that you mention: `user@example.com (Full Name)`

```
>>> e2 = "<az@example.com> az"
>>> parsed2 = parseaddr(e2)
>>> parsed2
('', 'az@example.com')
>>>
```

Is there really a formatting where full name comes after the email?

**EDIT** (re: Adam Bernier answer)

My try about how the regex works (probably not correct):

```
r    # raw string
<     # first limit character
(     # what is inside () is matched     
[       # indicates a set of characters
^         # start of string
>         # start with this and go backward?
]       # end set of characters
+       # repeat the match
)     # end group
>    # end limit character
```

Comment: The example you used, '<az@example.com> az', is not a valid format, which is why parseaddr() didn't handle it.  However, 'az@example.com (az)' is a valid format, and parseaddr() does handle it.

Comment: P.S.  Yes, the address-first parenthetical-comment-after is a valid format and does exist in the wild.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4  You really, honestly, truly should not use a regexp here when an already-proven parser is available for free.

Comment: @Forest: Yes, thanks. I am using the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use **regex** try something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> email_string = "az <az@example.com>"
>>> re.findall(r'<([^>]+)>', email_string)
['az@example.com']
```

Note that the above regex handles multiple addresses...

```
>>> email_string2 = "az <az@example.com>, bz <bz@example.com>"
>>> re.findall(r'<([^>]+)>', email_string2)
['az@example.com', 'bz@example.com']
```

but this simpler regex doesn't:

```
>>> re.findall(r'<(.*)>', email_string2)
['az@example.com>, bz <bz@example.com'] # matches too much
```

---

Using **slices**—which I think you meant to say instead of "**lists**"—seems more convoluted, e.g.:

```
>>> email_string[email_string.find('<')+1:-1]
'az@example.com'
```

and if multiple:

```
>>> email_strings = email_string2.split(',')
>>> for s in email_strings:
...   s[s.find('<')+1:-1]
...
'az@example.com'
'bz@example.com'
```

Comment: Great thanks! I don't exactly understand how it works, so I added my understanding for reference. I would appreciate if you could correct it.

Comment: I just saw your edits. It's great that it can handle multiple emails, I did not realize that. And thanks for the `slice` examples!

Comment: Beware: this approach will not work with the `user@example.com (Full Name)` email header field format, nor a field with angle brackets in the full name like `"Joe <User" <joe@example.com>`.  Also, I'm not sure how you intend to do a regex or substring search on an App Engine datastore.  See my answer for a faster, safer, more reliable solution that will work on App Engine.

Comment: Thanks, @ʇsәɹoɈ. For the record your answer should be the accepted one. I was catering too much to the use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than storing the entire contents of a To: or From: header field as an opaque string, why don't you parse incoming email and store email address separately from full name?  See [`email.utils.parseaddr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr).  This way you don't have to use complicated, slow pattern matching when you want to look up an address.  You can always reassemble the fields using [`formataddr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.formataddr).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I am looking into it. For now I am just testing to send/receive email by using a couple of given emails and the regex solution works for testing. When I understand how `email.utils` work I will switch to that.

Comment: added an Edit testing `parseaddr()`. Thanks.